# Data Consolidation for ETL pipeline

Tags: sql, mongodb, hadoop, cassandra, etl

I am currently planning to move some data sources to one place for posterior analysis.

Currently I have any data sources (databases) such as:

- MSSQL
- Mysql
- mongodb
- Postgres

Cassandra will be use for analytics in a big data pipeline. What is the best way to migrate any source to a Cassandra cluster?

Comment: Not sure why Kafka was tagged

Comment: What about Kafka Connector?

Comment: Kafka Connect will work. Nothing about your question mentioned Kafka. Kafka Connect JDBC or Sqoop needs JDBC connectors to reach MSSQL/MySQL/Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will highly recommend using NiFi for this use case. Some of benefits that I can outline right away.

- Inbuilt "Processors" available for reading the data from all listed data sources and writing to Cassandra.
- Very high throughput with low latency.
- Rapid data acquisition pipeline development without writing a lot of code.
- Ability to do "Change Data Capture" very easily later in your project, if needed.
- Provides a highly concurrent model without a developer having to worry about the typical complexities of concurrency.
- Is inherently asynchronous which allows for very high throughput and natural buffering even as processing and flow rates fluctuate
- The resource-constrained connections make critical functions such as back-pressure and pressure release very natural and intuitive.
- The points at which data enters and exits the system as well as how it flows through are well understood and easily tracked
- And biggest of all, OPEN SOURCE.

You can refer [Apache NiFi homepage](https://nifi.apache.org/) for more information.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Streamsets is another option

Comment: What about Kafka Connector or Apache Sqoop?